# Custom CI Directory for gitlab-runner

Tags: git, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a project on gitlab that uses a custom CI/CD directory like so:

```
my-project/
├─ .ci/
│  ├─ gitlab-ci.yml
│  ├─ local-ci.sh
├─ .git/
├─ my-project/
├─ tests/
```

Where local-ci.sh is a script that invokes `gitlab-runner` on the pipeline in `gitlab-ci.yml`.

On gitlab you can identify a custom path for the gitlab-ci.yml file, so the pipeline works when I push to the remote repository. I'd like to run the same CI pipeline on my local machine using `gitlab-runner` and Docker before pushing to the remote repository.

The issue I'm running into is when I run the pieline locally, `gitlab-runner` expects the `.git` directory to be in the same directory as the `gitlab-ci.yml` script. Is there a way to configure where the `git` directory is when running `gitlab-runner`?

Specifically, from this command (Linting is a stage of the pipeline):

```
gitlab-runner exec docker Linting
```

I get this error:

```
fatal: '<absolute path>/my-project/.ci' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

When I copy the `gitlab-ci.yml` script into the root directory, and change the working directory in the `local-ci.sh` script, the pipeline finishes without issue. Any thoughts?

EDIT: adding notes about the errors and copying the CI script.

Comment: Have you consider using includes https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html

Comment: In my understanding, includes are a way to include extra yaml files, not to identify a remote repository for the CI pipeline to use.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution would be to add a file `my-project/gitlab-ci.yml` which just includes the *real* `gitlab-ci.yml`.

```yaml
include:
    - local: .ci/gitlab-ci.yml
```

This should solve your problem, because

- gitlab-ci will find your settings
- technically the the `gitlab-ci.yml` and the `.git` directory are in the same directory, so `gitlab-runner` should be fine.
- all of your real ci-config is still in one directory

You might even get away with using an symbolic link instead:

```sh
ln -s .ci/gitlab-ci.yml gitlab-ci.yml
```

This would arguably be even cleaner (because there is no code added to your reposity, just a link). You'd have to try if all of your tools can work with symbolic links (I suspect they can).